# How to post http after oncreate complete?

Tags: android, android-activity, http-post

I have a `MainActivity` that has `onCreate` method in it. In that class, it should load the `layout` and post data to `server`. As long as the activity started, it becomes blank and only go to the next activity `SignUpActivity`. what I need is the `MainActivity` layout will show first and then `execute` the `httpPost`.

---

*Here are my code*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    context = this;

    new MainAsyncTask().execute(""); // where should i put this code? here??
}

   private class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String result = null;
        String url = "some url";
        Log.i("Post", "Post HTTP");

        HttpPostHelper.postData(url); // method to post the http. i made myself
        intent = new Intent(context, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return result;
    }
}

}
```

i just want that the `MainAsyncTask.execute("")` is executed after the layout is fully shown on the device.

**SOLVED**

I move the `new MainAsyncTask().execute("");` and add it here, and it works fine:

```html
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  new MainAsyncTask().execute("");
}
```

Comment: `layout is fully shown on the device` what does it mean?

Comment: yes, you place it right

Comment: @maveň: when the MainActivity is called, it just go blank and doesnt show the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);. 
I want this activity show the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) first and then execute the MainAsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in onStart() method of activity

Answer (score 0):

calling on `AsynTask` seems ok but you shouldn't call your intent in `doInBackground()`

call it in `onPostExecute()` method

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result){
intent = new Intent(context, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: thank you. but it still doesnt show the MainActivity layout. it just go to the SignUpActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `Thread.sleep` before `startActivity` to give the main layout some time to load and show. You should also call the `startActivity` in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

as per your code it should be like this.  Take care of @ `doinbackground()` as here it is not correct.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        context = this;

    new MainAsyncTask().execute(""); // where should i put this code? here??
}

   private class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {



protected void onPreExecute( ){

//start Progressbar
    progressBar.show();

}


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String result = null;
        String url = "some url";
        Log.i("Post", "Post HTTP");

        HttpPostHelper.postData(url); // method to post the http. i made myself

        return result;
    }



 protected void onPostExecute(String result){

//stuff u want in main thread
    progressBar.cancell();
    intent = new Intent(context, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
}

}
```